# How to setup redux-promise so that axios request has time to finish?

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, axios

New to react and redux so bear with me.

I have a react container that calls an action when loaded. The action returns an axios request and ideally the reducer would return the results and update the state. However, it doesn't appear that the results from the axios request are finishing.

I'm getting an error that `this.props.sparts.map` is not a function and `sparts` is empty when I print `this.props` so I'm assuming the request is not finishing.

**Component**

```
class Spart extends Component {
  renderSpart() {
    let sparts = []

    console.log('please print something')
    console.log(this.props)

    this.props.sparts.map((spart, index) => {
      sparts.push(
          <div class="ui column wide spart-container">
            <div class="fake-img"></div>
            <div class="audio-container">
              {spart.song}
            </div>
            <div class="writing-container">
              {spart.writing}
            </div>
          </div>
      )
    })

    return _.chunk(sparts, 3).map(function(group) {
      return <div class="three column row">{group}</div>
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ui equal width grid spart-container">
        {this.renderSpart()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('mapStateToProps')
  console.log(state)
  return {
    sparts: state.sparts
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ getSparts: getSparts }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Spart);
```

**Action**

```
export function getSparts() {
  const request = axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/sparts`)

  return {
    type: GET_SPARTS,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case GET_SPARTS:
    return [ action.payload.data, ...state ]
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

**Middleware**

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem for async operations if you don't check the render part with a condition. Use something like this:

```
{this.props.sparts.length > 0 && this.renderSpart()}
```

One issue is shown up after looking the code more deeply, getSparts() action is never invoked. So the solution is invoking it in a suitable lifecycle method like componentDidMount as OP did:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSparts();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the request is still never updating the state of the app

Comment: I'm not familiar with redux-promise (I prefer redux-thunk) but people use this with redux-actions I think. But, where do you invoke your getSparts() action? I can't see it in your Spart component. I couldn't see this yesterday.

Comment: I just added this ```componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSparts();
  }```. So that was one issue. I thought it was auto-invoked

Comment: No, it is not auto invoked as you figured it out. You should invoke it where you need it. Now, can you see your sparts data as your prop after component re-renders?

Comment: Yeah, the request is being made now. Working on some CORS issues now :) I'll mark your answer as right and upvote my `componentDidMount` comment